# JLabel Right-Justified Icon and Text

Tags: java, swing, icons, jlabel

Is it possible to create a `JLabel` with a right-justified icon and text and the icon is on the right, like this:

[image]

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932389/how-to-right-justify-icon-in-a-jlabel) question, but is it really the best approach?

Comment: Also consider a `JList` or `JTable` [renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

Comment: Here's a related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7620726/230513) for tinkering.

Comment: That answer is given by one of **THE BEST** in Java Swing :-) You name it and the person has one example coming to you from the **MAGIC BOX**

Comment: @GagandeepBali: You are too kind. This related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2834484/230513) illustrates using an `Icon` in a renderer.

Comment: Found another good trashgod sample :) :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932389/how-to-right-justify-icon-in-a-jlabel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps this would be more what you're looking for?  It should align everything on the right side of the panel (more so than the example you were looking at):

[image: Screenshot of Code]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TempProject
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Box mainContent = Box.createVerticalBox();
                mainContent.add(TempProject.getLabel("abc"));
                mainContent.add(TempProject.getLabel("Longer"));
                mainContent.add(TempProject.getLabel("Longerest"));
                mainContent.add(TempProject.getLabel("Smaller"));

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
                frame.setContentPane(mainContent);    
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static JLabel getLabel(String text){
        JLabel c = new JLabel(text);
        c.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEADING);
        c.setAlignmentX(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        c.setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("FileChooser.detailsViewIcon"));
        return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The [example cited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932389/how-to-right-justify-icon-in-a-jlabel/2933256#2933256) uses layout and label properties for right/left justification.

Additionally, consider implementing the `Icon` interface in a `JList` [renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), where `setHorizontalAlignment()` and `setVerticalAlignment()` may be used to control the relative geometry. This related [`TableCellRenderer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833482/how-to-represent-double-values-as-circles-in-a-2d-matrix-in-java/2834484#2834484) illustrates the principle.

[image]