# Align text and icon differently in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jlabel, imageicon

i'm trying to create a JLabel that has text aligned left and icon aligned right, i tried this code:

```
_ip = new JLabel(ip);
_ip.setFont(boldFont);
_ip.setBounds(5, 0, 100, 50);
_ip.setIcon(images.ipBan);
_ip.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
_ip.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
add(_ip);
```

And this is what i get:

[image: Alignment preview]

*The red image shows the actual image alignment, the gray one shows where i want my image to be.*

If i add

```
_ip.setAlignmentX(JLabel.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
```

Nothing happens, and if i add

```
_ip.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
```

Icon is aligned right, but also text is aligned right, and i want it to align left

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Won't adding a few spaces solves the problem?I mean `jLabel.setText("99.222.22.230     (FEW SPACES)     ")`

Comment: No, this will be a fetched-from-db IPs list, if i choose to add some spaces it means i should know every IP i'm loading, but in fact i don't as they are loaded from a db, so i can't just add spaces

Comment: I know it's a ugly way but your ip string+ " (SPACE)" will do the job.

Comment: There must be a way (tricky or not) to do that, spaces are just a workaround that i don't want to use, mainly because the font i'm using is not monospaced, so if i put some labels into a JList, every icon will be misaligned to others

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use a `JPanel` with a suitable layout, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2933256/230513).

[image]

Comment: That was wondeful EG +1, I was about to post an EG on sum length of the string stuff lol

Comment: You are welcome! @joeyrohan: Might be possible with `TextLayout` in a custom `LabelUI`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3597688/230513).

Answer (score 6):

please DYM???

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CenteredJLabel {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("CenteredJLabel");
    private Icon errorIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");

    public CenteredJLabel() {
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.add(label);
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        label.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setIcon(errorIcon);
        label.setIconTextGap(20);
        label.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                CenteredJLabel centeredJLabel = new CenteredJLabel();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CenteredJLabel {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private JLabel labelOne = new JLabel("CenteredJLabel");
    private JLabel labelTwo = new JLabel("1.1.1.1");
    private JLabel labelThree = new JLabel("192.168.255.255");
    private JLabel labelFour = new JLabel("192.168.255.255");
    private Icon errorIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
    private Icon infoIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
    private Icon warnIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon");
    private Icon questnIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.questionIcon");
    private JPanel panelTwo = new JPanel();

    public CenteredJLabel() {
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 0, 10, 10));

        labelOne.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        labelOne.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        labelOne.setIcon(errorIcon);
        labelOne.setIconTextGap(20);
        labelOne.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        panel.add(labelOne);

        labelTwo.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        labelTwo.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        labelTwo.setIcon(infoIcon);
        labelTwo.setIconTextGap(20);
        labelTwo.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        panel.add(labelTwo);

        labelThree.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        labelThree.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        labelThree.setIcon(warnIcon);
        labelThree.setIconTextGap(20);
        labelThree.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        panel.add(labelThree);

        panelTwo.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panelTwo.setOpaque(false);
        panelTwo.add(labelFour, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panelTwo.add(new JLabel(questnIcon), BorderLayout.EAST);
        panel.add(panelTwo);

        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                CenteredJLabel centeredJLabel = new CenteredJLabel();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. If you remove the `frame.pack()` instruction and simply do `frame.setSize(500,300)`, it will just center the label, that is not what i want to do

Comment: @Harlandraka I don't think he is trying to show the frame on the center, but see the spacing between the icon and text.

Comment: @joeyrohan I'm not saying he's showing the frame on the center, i'm saying that this solution simply centers the text and the icon on the JLabel, but this is not what i need, so this is not a solution to my problem, and also spacing between text and icon isn't a solution, because i don't know how many chars my text will contain

Comment: @Harlandraka But you always know the max : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx .What exactly you want?May be `Label.setIconTextGap()` helps?

Comment: @joeyrohan Using the icon text gap is the same as using spaces, if i use i.e. `_ip.setIconTextGap(15)`, then a label with text `151.33.58.1` will have the text and icon aligment that i want, but if my text is `1.1.1.1` it will not align correctly.

Comment: @Harlandraka it all depends on the size of you label.SOk here's a trick (i don't know a simple way) set the icon gap as per the length of your string ..should I try?

Comment: @Harlandraka the above example is perfect it will align correctly.Try for inputs.+1 for the answer.

Comment: @joeyrohan really? Check my first comment, just size manually the frame and you'll see that this is not what i need. Then try to change the text length, and you will see that the icon position will be based on the text length

Comment: @Harlandraka then you have to add LayoutManager(Box or BorderLayout) to JLabel and put there a JLabel with text and another JLabel with Icon, see my edit here

Comment: @mKorbel the problem is still the same, the "i" icon is not aligned with all other icons

Comment: @Harlandraka please do you understand how I layed JPanel with two JLabels, then in all cases text starting on left side and Icon is sticked on right side, about basic layout ....

Comment: for active JComponent to put Icon to the undecorated JButton

Comment: Yes i understand, but it's not what i want, trashgod answer is what i'm looking for.